# Are there an odd number of numbers in the unit interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, parity

Or, four questions that I think are equivalent, but I don't know if will be thought to make sense:

1. Are there an odd number of numbers in $[0, 1]$?
2. Are there an even number of numbers in $[0, 1)$?
3. Are there an even number of numbers in $(0, 1]$?
4. Are there an odd number of numbers in $(0, 1)$?

My basic reasoning is that there must be the same number of (real) numbers in $[0, 0.5)$ as in $(0.5, 1]$, meaning that there are an even number of numbers in their union, and therefore additionally including $0.5$ there are an odd number of numbers in $[0, 1]$.

Seems straightforward, but uncountable sets aren't, and therefore I don't know if their parity is a sensible concept to talk about...

Comment: This does not work even with countable sets.  You can easily find a bijection from non-negative integers to positive  integers such as $f(n)=n+1$ so (a) they would have the same number of elements so the same parity and  (b) they would have a difference of $1$ in their number of elements so different parities.  This can be extended to uncountable sets with countable subsets

Answer (score 3):

The concepts of odd and even only apply (directly) to finite numbers. There isn't a direct way to talk about infinite (countable or uncountable) sets having an even or odd number of elements.

If you want to talk about even and odd in the infinite setting, you can look into [even and odd ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_ordinals). The [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) are a different way to generalize the natural numbers into numbers that are "infinite."

To get you started, $\omega$ is the size of the set of $\mathbb{N}$ (the set of natural numbers). This is the smallest infinite ordinal and its even. Then, you can take $\omega + 1$, $\omega + 2$, etc... which are odd, even, etc... However, from the perspective of "size", all of these ordinals (and a lot more) are all $\aleph_0$ in "size". There are ordinals of bigger sizes, but you need to do a fair amount of work to get to them.

Ordinals are extremely cool, I highly recommend looking into them.